# How to re render the dom-if template

Tags: javascript, polymer

How to re render the dom-if template. If function is used instead of boolean variable.

Here goes the jsBin for the above query...
https://jsbin.com/lacoguy/edit?html,console,output

I'm trying to re-check the conditions on dom-if templates and re-render them once the dependent values changes.

There is a way for re-rendering template with dom-reapeat. It works like

```
this.$.templateId.render();
```

No same luck for template with dom-if.

Comment: It would be good if you could also paste the relevant parts of your code here for future visitors to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, I saw that the computed function depends on the property `selectedPage`, so you should make that property an argument to the function. The function will now re-evaluate whenever the value of `selectedPage`changes.

```
  <template dom-if="isBookingPage(selectedPage)">
    <span>Booking page toolbar rendered</span>
  </template>
```